# Google-apps-scripts list all settings for all users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-audit-api

I'm new to working with G suite and Google apps script. I haven't found this described on their page. Is there a possibility for a Gsuite admin to list all the settings/policies for users? 
Thanks.

Comment: make a little bit more search..!

Comment: As far as I know, [Gsuite Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/) will be deprecated soon.